# How do I remove duplicate items in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am a SQL beginner.
I have a table with the following fields in MariaDB
(I've added id which has auto-increment.)
[image]

Now, I need to remove rows having same DATE.
One way to do it if this is data frame of pandas,

```
df = df.drop_duplicates ()
```

How can I do this in SQL?

sample data

```
date/open/high/low/close/volume    
2019.02.04 00:00:00 13.34303    13.34303    13.34143    13.34303    4
2019.02.04 00:01:00 13.34303    13.34303    13.34303    13.34303    2
★ 2019.02.04 00:02:00   13.34303    13.34323    13.34303    13.34323    2
★2019.02.04 00:02:00    13.34303    13.34323    13.34303    13.34323    2
2019.02.04 00:04:00 13.33663    13.33743    13.33623    13.33733    86
2019.02.04 00:05:00 13.33734    13.33734    13.33613    13.33613    70
```

desired data

```
2019.02.04 00:00:00 13.34303    13.34303    13.34143    13.34303    4
2019.02.04 00:01:00 13.34303    13.34303    13.34303    13.34303    2
★2019.02.04 00:02:00    13.34303    13.34323    13.34303    13.34323    2
2019.02.04 00:03:00 13.34333    13.34333    13.33664    13.33664    14
2019.02.04 00:04:00 13.33663    13.33743    13.33623    13.33733    86
2019.02.04 00:05:00 13.33734    13.33734    13.33613    13.33613    70
```

My Environmental Detail:

> Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
>  XAMPP Version: 7.2.8 Control Panel
>   Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
>  
>   127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
>  MariaDB SSL is not being used 
>  
>   10.1.34-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution Protocol Version: 10 
>  character set: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

For comment
[image]

For the answered command
[image]

Any Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain what *you* mean by "duplicate".

Comment: I've meant "duplicate" with "(number of same date item)>=2"

Comment: which data type is you date column (first column)  ? and what is the name of the columns

Comment: your table have a id? a primary key?  if you have a not a primary key you can't delete single row

Comment: AH! I don't have! I'll try setting the key and command given in Answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to delete every records whose date appears more than once in the table,you may proceed as follows :

```
DELETE t 
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT datetime FROM mytable GROUP BY datetime HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t1 ON t1.datetime = t.datetime;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C9ySmED3GNLYTJ19nkXhq/0)**

---

After your question was edited, I understand that you want to delete *one* of the duplicate rows, while keeping the other.

To achieve this, you will need a column that uniquely identify each record in the groups of duplicates. Let's call that column  `id`.

```
DELETE t FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN mytable t1 ON t1.datetime = t.datetime AND t1.id < t.id;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C9ySmED3GNLYTJ19nkXhq/1)**

Comment: thanks you for example, but ,SQL returned the error ;SQL 0A80E90FC  (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tWHERE t.date IN (    SELECT date FROM `forex`.`eurusd ask` GROUP BY date HA' at line 1

Comment: @Xminer : I think it's because `datae` is a SQL keyword, I updated the query to use a table alias, please check

Comment: @Xminer the problem is no space between the t and `WHERE` keyword see the error part `tWHERE t.date IN (...)` .

Comment: @scaisEdge and Rick James : yes, OP was edited after I answered... I updated my answer just now.

Comment: @GMB - `date` is what I would call a "semi-reserved" word.  It, and a small number of other keywords, are ok as column names in _most_ contexts.

Comment: @GMB I've added id as primary key to table,and I've tried the command. but same error returned....is there anything which I can try?

Comment: @Xminer : can you try `DELETE t FROM mytable t WHERE EXISTS...` ? I think that what was causing the issue. I also changed my queries to match your edited columns names

Comment: @GMB error was changed! SQL 0A80E90FC  (1093): Table 't' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: @Xminer : OK, I gave a good second look at your question, rebuilt the queries and tested them in a DB Fiddle. This hopefully will work for you now !

Comment: Welcome @Xminer... And sorry for the numerous tries before success !

Answer (score 0):

If this about duplicates across the whole row, I would suggest re-loading the table.  You can use a temporary table for this purpose:

```
create table temp_t as
    select distinct *
    from t;
```

Then, you can put this back into the original table as:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t
    select * 
    from temp_t;
```

Normally, I would include all columns in the `insert`.  But for this type of processing, the code used `select *` to generate the temporary table and it is just inserting back into the original table.

By using `truncate`/`insert`, you save a lot of overhead on logging and locking the table.

Comment: I thought this would work,but...  `SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) c FROM (SELECT * FROM `forex`.`temp_t` ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 9000) AS A GROUP BY DATE HAVING c > 1;` show more than 2....(duplicate rows remained...)

Comment: @Xminer . . . You have no unique identifier for each row.  Under those circumstances, I would recommend either adding an auto-increment column or just regenerating the table (as this answer suggests).

Comment: I've already have ids(am I wrong? plz check,I updated my tables information)

Comment: @Xminer . . . If you have a unique id, then your rows are not duplicates.  You should not change your question after it has been answered.

Comment: no,even though the table has unique id which I've just added,it has the rows which has the duplicated date.